# WiFi: Internet doesn't work, local network does

Tags: windows-xp, router, internet, wireless-networking, local

I have a problem with the Internet connection thru WiFi.

Some time ago I had reinstalled OS (XP Sp3) on a notebook (Samsung R560 with a WLAN adapter that's specified as *'Intel 802.11a/b/g/n 1x2 (MIMO) / Intel 802.11a/b/g/n 3x3 (MIMO) / Atheros 802.11b/g*'). Then (I understand that 'then' doesn't mean 'therefore') I faced the following problem: I could access to local network, but not to the Internet.

ISP's broadband Internet cable is connected to WiFi router ASUS WL-500, having local IP address 192.168.1.1 (DHCP is disabled). Both 2 and 3 are assigned to a Windows server and another notebook. 192.168.1.4 is assigned to the Samsung notebook. I had installed a custom Intel utility on top of the WLAN driver, then (after the problems begin) uninstalled it, so now I have the naked driver.

From time to time, the Internet connection gets broken: no external sites are available, Skype is out, Outlook can't get e-mails. Nevertheless, I still have access to the local network, say, \192.168.1.2\c$. The other machines are still connected to the Internet thru the same router.

What can be the problem root? What have I look at?

Comment: Can you ping the gateway address?

Comment: I'll try this the next time when it's corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off energy-saving mode for the WiFi adapter, it's often buggy.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've got the IP address; but you need a default gateway and a DNS server IP configured on the laptop as well. The default gateway is the router (sounds like 192.168.1.1) and you can use any available DNS (like 4.2.2.4 or 8.8.8.8).

Comment: Yes, I have already set the default gateway to 192.168.1.1. I'm not sure the Internet is available at all if I have not. The problem is *something* gets corrupted irregularly and I have no ideas what it can be.

Comment: Try calling your ISP yet?

Comment: As the other machines *are* connected to the Internet the same time and thru the same router, it looks irrelevant.